# 301 редирект с помощью .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Есть сылки вида

```
сайт/shop/zhenskaya-obuv/sapogi/86001
```

Нужно сделать 301 редирект на

```
сайт/zhenskaya-obuv/sapogi/86001
```

то есть убрать `/shop/` вне зависимости от дальнейшего контента

```
сайт/shop/бла/бла/бла 
->
сайт/бла/бла/бла
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteRule ^shop/(.+)$ сайт/$1 [R=301,L]